# strcat alternative issue C++

Tags: c++, operators, strcat

I am working on a project which was initially sampled in C but want to work on it in C++.

There is a section where a strcat() is used, I have been told to use an alternative. I have found one [here](http://cs.stmarys.ca/~porter/csc/ref/c_cpp_strings.html), but when I try those the compiler gives me the following error:

> error: invalid operands of types `char*' and`char*' to binary `operator+'

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Edit:

Here's the portion of the code that doesn't work

```
FILE *FileOpen(string *fname, string* mode){
FILE *fp;
string *str = "";

str += "tmp/"; //all files to be created in temporary sub directory
str += fname;
if((fp=fopen(str,mode))==NULL){
fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open file: %s\n", &fname);
exit(1);
}
FileReader(fname);
return(fp);
}
```

Edit 2:
For those wondering why I have FileReader: it's for part 2 of the project. Disassembling a code.

Comment: Yes, because `char*` is not the same as `std::string`.

Comment: Please post the erroneous code

Comment: "Is there something I am doing wrong?"

Obviously yes. You wouldn't get errors if you didn't. Now if you meant to ask _what_ you're doing wrong... How in the name of goodness are we supposed to know without seeing your code?

Comment: Please throw that reference far far away.  I found this little gem: `strcpy(str, strcat(str1, str2));` along with the claim it's the same as `str = str1+str2;`.  (It's not, as it changes `str1` and will cause undefined behavior if `str1` was a constant / string literal or didn't have enough storage allocated for the concatenation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for posting your code; now the problem is readily apparent.

You should use string objects, not pointers to them.

```
FILE *FileOpen(string fname, string mode)
{
    string str = "";

    str += "tmp/"; //all files to be created in temporary sub directory
    str += fname;
    FILE *fp = fopen(str.c_str(), mode.c_str());
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file: %s\n", fname.c_str());
        exit(1);
    }
    FileReader(fname);
    return fp;
}
```

A good next step would be to move to I/O functions that accept `std::string` arguments, so you don't have to say `.c_str()` everywhere.

I'm also confused why you have `FileReader(fname)` inside your file-opening function.  That violates the Single-Responsibility-Prinicple, twice.  Opening a file should not cause it to be read, and the code reading the file should use a `FILE*` and not care what the filename is (except perhaps for generation of error messages).

Comment: I have the FileReader for the second portion of the project (disassembling a program).

Comment: @JulioGarcia: Of course you need `FileReader` somewhere, but not inside this function.  It should probably be called from your main routine, after the call to this function.

Comment: Ok, got it. Now I have a problem on FileReader. Shall I put it here or on another question? >.>;;

Comment: Thank you @OlafDietsche, it's sort of both. Related to FileOpen and it's own little world.

Comment: @JulioGarcia Then it's your call, which one you choose. Although a new question usually draws more attention than an old one, which already has several answers.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Thanks for the tip. I made a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown any code, but I suspect you had something like this

```
char *s1 = "Hello, ", *s2 = "world!";
char buf[50];
strcpy(buf, s1);
strcat(buf, s2);
```

and now you changed it to

```
char *s1 = "Hello, ", *s2 = "world!";
char buf[50];
buf = s1 + s2;
```

This doesn't work, as you already noticed. You must change the char pointers and char array to `std::string` as well

```
std::string s1 = "Hello, ", s2 = "world!";
std::string buf = s1 + s2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is using `char *` as strings, then `strcat` is probably the right function for you. Of course, the C++ solution is to use `std::string`, in which case you can just use `+` - since there is binary `operator+` available for `std::string`.

Comment: Well, I change char to string and get the same result.

Comment: How on earth can you get `error: invalid operands of types char*' andchar*' to binary `operator+'` from std::string? Or did you just mean "I get an error" when you say "Same result"? I guess my skills in guessing your code didn't work.. ;)

Comment: @MatsPetersson, I think the OP might have done `std::string s = "abc" + "def";` or something similar.

Comment: @JulioGarcia: You're not supposed to change `char` to `string`, which would leave you with `string*`.  You're suppsosed to change `char*` to `string`.

Answer (score 0):

well, C++ has a string class `std::string` whose operator+ performs concatenation. But you have to create one first.

so the expression`"abc" + "def"` doesn't compile, but `std::string("abc")+"def"` works fine.

alternatively you can write something like

```
std::string s("abc");
s += "def";
```

similarly,

```
std::string s = "abc";
s += "def";
```

if you want to concatenate a large amount of text, and care about the performance, consider using `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: Why do you think an ostringstream would be more performant for just concatenating strings?

Comment: @yonil, All of the conforming C++11 implementations do.

Comment: @yonil: And you don't think `std::stringstream` uses contiguous memory?  Exponential buffer expansion is the reason it's faster, not anything to do with discontiguity.

Comment: I wrote complete nonsense in that comment before, sorry about that.