# FileReader issue C++

Tags: c++, file

On an [old question I posted here earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056905/strcat-alternative-issue-c/15057000#comment21170026_15057000), I have asked about an issue I had on a FileOpen function. This new question regards the second part: a FileReader.

I made the changes, and still have compiler errors.

Here's the troublesome code:

```
FILE *FileReader(FILE *fname){
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(fname);

    if(inputFile){
        string line = "";
        //int num_chars;

        while(getline(inputFile, line)){
            //num_chars = strlen(text) + 1;
            //line = (string *)malloc(sizeof(string)*num_chars)
            int i = 0;
            if(i <= 3 ){
                storString[i] = line;
                storage[i] = atoi(storString[i].c_str());
                i++;
            }
            else{
                string firstTwo = line.substr(0,1);
                const int hex = atoi(firstTwo.c_str());
                setOperations(hex);
                string commandOne = firstTwo.substr(0,0); //first part of command
                string commandTwo = firstTwo.substr(1,1); //second part of command and n-i flags
                string restFlags = line.substr(2,2); //xbpe flags
                rest = line.substr(3);
                int disp = atoi(rest.c_str());

                if(format == "fmt2"){
                    string rOne = line.substr(2,2);
                    int registerOne = atoi(rOne.c_str());
                    string rTwo = line.substr(3,3);
                    int registerTwo = atoi(rTwo.c_str());
                    registerOperation(hex, registerOne, registerTwo);
                    break;
                }
                setFlags(commandTwo, restFlags, disp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following errors are outputted:

a1/a1.cpp: In function `FILE* FileReader(FILE*)`:
a1/a1.cpp:338: error: no matching function for call to `std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(FILE*&)`
/opt/local/bin/../lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/fstream:570: note: candidates are: `void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(con
st char*, std::_Ios_Openmode)` [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]

Edit:

See those commented out lines. I also tried those, but have no idea how to implement them. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what are the compiler errors? We can't even try compiling because we don't know which headers you are including or missing

Comment: Forgot that one >.>;;

Already edited.

Comment: check this out: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inputfile.open() method expects a c-style string of the file name as an argument; it can also be a variable storing that name as a value. Let's say the file name is inputFile.txt, you could do something like:

```
inputFile.open("inputFile.txt");
```

You can also do this:

```
string fileName = "inputFile.txt";
inputFile.open(fileName.c_str());
```

Also, a comment about a later part in the code: instead of using `if(inputfile)`, use the is_open() method. So, you would write `if(inputfile.is_open())`. The method returns a boolean value, depending on whether or not opening the file was successful.

Comment: Ok, I changed it to string. But I get the same line, with FILE being replaced with &string

Comment: That's not enough, because the argument of the open() method must be a C-STYLE string; that is, a character array terminated with the '\0' character. In order to get this from a string object, you have to call the c_str() method, as shown in the response I provided. Also, make sure that, if you changed the parameter in the method, you also change the argument in the caller function to a string.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/

```
inputFile.open is being passed a `FILE *` but needs `const char *`
```

try passing it a hardcoded string like `"some_file.txt"` or pass it an actual `const char *`

Comment: What if the file is not .txt, but .sic?

Comment: if it's a file containing text, the extension doesn't matter.